# Class library wth EF core 2.1 ? No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

Tags: entity-framework-core

Im trying to setup a class library project with EF core 2.1 and use this class library from an .NET core api project.  When I attempt to reverse engineer my schema into a dbcontext, I get an error complaining about missing EF command.

Class library csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.0" />

  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

donet command

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.;Database=MyDb;user id=my-user;password=my-pwd;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -c LastMileContext -o Data
```

error:

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
```

So after reading a few other threads on this, I changed my csproj file to look like this in the ItemGroup section

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now the EF command runs and I get my entity classes.  My question is WHY do I yet have to manually add something to the csproj file?  Is there not another way?  Is the recommended way?  Seems maybe like I missed a dotnet command step or something?

Also, looks like im not the only one who has ran into these issues
https://fpnotebook.wordpress.com/2017/11/12/solution-entity-framework-core-and-net-core-class-libraries-2-0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from .NET Core SDK 2.1.300 cli supports so called [.NET Core Global Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools) and there is no need to manually add these tools into your csproj file.

All you need to do just call `dotnet tool install -g toolname` similar as in `npm`. You can find some information about available tools in this [repo](https://github.com/natemcmaster/dotnet-tools/blob/master/README.md).

`dotnet ef` is already included in 2.1.300 SDK CLI.

I will suggest you to [download](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows) and install .NET Core SDK 2.1.300 for this global tools support but still use .NET Core 2.0 if you don't have plans to migrate to .NET Core 2.1.